# Why when I tried of compile a solution don't create (Debug or Release) folders on Bin c#

Tags: c#, build, compilation

I tried of compile a solution don't create (Debug or Release) folders on Bin

In Some projects this is the structure":

```
> ---Project Folder
> -------Bin
> -------file1.dll
> -------file2.dll
```

And in other this is:

```
> ---Project Folder
> -------Bin
> ----------Debug(or Relase)
> -------------file1.dll
> -------------file2.dll
```

I need the second structure for all the projects, what can I do?

Comment: Are they different project types?  Are the project files configured differently?

Comment: change build output path of all your projects for debug and release

Comment: What project is your non (Debug or Release) folders?

Comment: Usualy webapplication projects not have (Debug or Release)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the folder structure in your project properties and set the bin directory at any place

Project Properties --> Build --> Output Path